# WooCommerce REST API AJAX Auth - 401 response

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, rest-api

I need to implement vuejs to load the categories of my store. I've read that the woocoomerce rest api need authenticate requets to work, so I'm trying to get the categories using oauth on localhost with https enabled:

```
// This is in my functions file to pass the parameters
// wp_localize_script( 'main', 'woo', 
    //   array(
    //     'ajaxurl' => 'wp-ajax.php',
    //     'timestamp' => time(),
    //     'hash' => hash_hmac(),
    //     'nonce'
    //   )
    // );
```

AJAX

```
// This is the JS part
//$.ajax({
        //method: 'GET',
        //url: 'wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories&oauth_consumer_key="+woo.consumer_key+"&oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp="+woo.timestamp+"&oauth_nonce="+woo.nonce+"&oauth_signature=+woo.hash',
        // beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        //   xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "OAuth " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        // },
```

I get always a 401 response code, I'm not able to authenticate using ajax. I want to use the wp_localize_script to pass the needed timestamp and auth, but I'm not able to find how to do it correctly.
Any  example will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I rewrite the che code using sally suggestion but I still get the 401 error response code.
Here is the updated code

PHP

```
wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/main.js', array('jquery'), null );
    $localize = array(
       'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
       // Securing your WordPress plugin AJAX calls using nonces
       'auth' => base64_encode('ck_32a46b36d90680e574e9de6456746a11cf07945:cs_0a6bd199a45c0b96e848a1401a14b18444fa46d8'),
    );
    wp_localize_script('main', 'wp', $localize);
    wp_enqueue_script('main');
```

JS

```
    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {},
      created: function(){
        $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories',
          headers: {
             'Authorization': "Basic "+ wp.auth
          },
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }
        });
      },
      destroyed: {},
      mounted: {},
    });
```

I'm on localhost with a self signed cert to have the https, maybe this can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the WooCommerce REST API documentation is available [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) and you should check it out.

Secondly, the examples below are using the `/wc/v3/products/categories` ("[List all product categories](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-product-categories)") endpoint.

And here's a proper way to authenticate your request using OAuth — it always works when authenticating over HTTPS and *it is the only accepted option for authenticating over HTTP*:

- It's up to you how to make the relevant variables available in JavaScript via `wp_localize_script()`. Or to implement the PHP code below in JavaScript.
- You can generate your WooCommerce REST API keys via the WordPress admin interface — WooCommerce → Settings → "Advanced" tab → REST API.

```php
// Define the request method.
$method = 'GET';
// Just set the second parameter to the proper endpoint, without /wp-json.
$url = get_rest_url( null, '/wc/v3/products/categories' );
// Define your keys.
$ck = '<put key here>'; // consumer key
$cs = '<put key here>'; // consumer secret

$params = [
    // Required parameters:
    'oauth_consumer_key'     => $ck,
    'oauth_timestamp'        => time(),
    'oauth_nonce'            => wp_create_nonce( time() ),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',

    // Parameters specific to the endpoint:
    'per_page' => 2,
];

// Sort the parameters and encode them into a single string.
uksort( $params, 'strcmp' );
$params2 = '';
foreach ( $params as $key => $value ) {
    $params2 .= ( $params2 ? '%26' : '' ) .
        rawurlencode( $key ) . '%3D' . rawurlencode( $value );
}

// Create the signature base string.
$sig_base = $method . '&' . rawurlencode( $url ) . '&' . $params2;
// And generate the signature base.
$sig = base64_encode( hash_hmac( 'sha1', $sig_base, $cs . '&', true ) );

// Add the required oauth_signature parameter.
$params['oauth_signature'] = $sig;
// And build the query string.
$query = http_build_query( $params );

// Then make request to this URL:
//$req_url = $url . '?' . $query;
```

And here are other options you can use, but only when authenticating over HTTPS, and you should know that these will expose your *consumer **secret** key*:

1. Use [HTTP Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) — set the HTTP `Authorization` header; i.e. `Authorization: Basic <base64 encoding of <consumer key>:<consumer secret>>`:

   ```js
   jQuery.ajax( {
       url: '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories',
       headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Basic <base64-encoded value here>'
       },
       ...
   } );
   ```

   In PHP, you can do `base64_encode( '<consumer key>:<consumer secret>' );` to get the base64-encoded value.

   *And make sure the `Authorization` header is enabled on the server.*
2. *Or* provide the consumer key/secret as query string parameters — e.g. `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?consumer_key=<KEY>&consumer_secret=<KEY>`:

   ```js
   jQuery.ajax( {
       url: '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?consumer_key=<key>&consumer_secret=<key>',
       ...
   } );
   ```

Another option when authenticating over HTTPS, is by using the standard cookie authentication as explained [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication):

```js
// This example provides the nonce as a query string parameter.
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: '/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?_wpnonce=<nonce>',
    ...
} );
```

You may also use [authentication plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins), but you will need to test them on your own.

Comment: I'm encoding the credentials in php using `base64_encode` and I'm passing the result string using the localize script, but I still get the 401 response from categories endpoint. I'm passing the headers in this way in ajax `headers: { 'Authorization': "Basic "+ wp.auth },`

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code, both PHP & JS? That way, I can give you better suggestions/ideas.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Have you checked if the server actually allows the `Authorization` header? Also, in your `$.ajax()` call, your `url` should start with `/wp-json/` and not `wp-json/` even if the script is linked to from the homepage. Even better, add a localized var that points to the root REST API URL and use the var in your scripts. (e.g. add `'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),` to the `wp_localize_script()` array)

Comment: No, I didn't checked if the server allow auth, I think it's enabled by default, I need to check apache settings right? I will consider to add the url as a variable like you suggested

Comment: I think it's probably not enabled or that Basic Auth is not allowed. But if it's the former, then try the steps [here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/2c568227ed887d582e3c644fac4e5b21).

Comment: The authorization header was disabled, I've added this directive to my localhost apache server config `SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1` . Now I need to test if all works as expected

Comment: no way to make the auth work. I only get 401 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104816/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-sialfa).

Comment: I'm looking at the function file of the custom theme where woocommerce is loaded, I've found that the users endopoint of wordpress are disabled, this because it can be a security issue to expose on the REST API the users endpoint, can be this a problem with the woocommerce authentication?

Comment: Here is the code I've found 
`add_filter('rest_endpoints', function($endpoints){
    if( isset($endpoints['/wp/v2/users']) ){
      unset($endpoints['/wp/v2/users']);
    }
    return $endpoints;
  });`

Comment: One way to find out, is temporarily comment out that code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below snippest, it works very well

```
function get_wc_all_products() {
    var authCode = btoa('ck**_---**-:cs_**-----**e');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://**YourSite**/wp-json/wc/v3/products',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "Basic " + authCode
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```